# Read HTTP request from a SOCKET in perl

Tags: perl, sockets, http, tcp, ssh

I have a problem with reading a socket in `PERL`.

The story goes like this :
`1.1.1.1` is my server
`2.2.2.2` is my other server that it is opened as ssh tunnel on `1.1.1.1`
`3.3.3.3` is my ip from `Mozilla Firefox`

I have a ssh tunnel opened on port `12345` and a `tcp.pl` "server" that is oppenning on port `2000` and it is **forwarding** all raw traffic to port `12345` then gets it back again.

I have oppened `Mozilla Firefox` and put at **SOCKS5** `1.1.1.1:2000` (the tcp.pl server), and when i surf the web, i surf with `2.2.2.2`'s ip, witch is good.

I wrote someware in my code to print all sockets that `tcp.pl` is getting with this command :

```
`print $buffer;`
```

The problem is that i can read **HTTP HEADERS** and i see stuff like

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1235518067.1410367631
Connection: keep-alive
```

witch is ok, but i don't quite get the **HTTP CONTENT** , i mean i don't get the **HTML code**. I sometimes get a part of the HTML CODE LIKE THIS

```
:G�� ��� <-- some wired characters
<html>...</html>
���lOP� <-- some wired characters
```

and sometimes i get

```
PuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTy
```

and a beep sound.

**the code (tcp.pl)**

an infinite loop that reads reads and reads ....

```
while (1) 
{
    for my $socket ($ioset->can_read) 
    {
        if($socket == $server) 
        {
            new_connection($server);
        }
        else 
        {
            next unless exists $socket_map{$socket};
            my $remote = $socket_map{$socket};
            my $buffer;

            # get data from main port
            my $read = $socket->sysread($buffer, 4096);
            if ($read) 
            {
                print $read; # gives a number like 43243 5436346456 34654643464
                print $buffer; # allways gives HTTP headers, and token is frequently distorted, showing characters like ":G�� ������lOP�" and some chunks of HTML CODE from time to time
                # sometimes i get output like "PuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTyPuTTy" and hearing some beeping sounds

                # forward data to the other port (in browser you see no differance)
                $remote->syswrite($buffer);
            }
            else {
                close_connection($socket);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this is because the fact that i don't order the packets properly, i mean i have to read SOCKETS and order by `ACK` and `SEQ` flags, then read it.

Now my main quession, how do i read the HTML content as it is?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to parse HTTP responses, perhaps you should familiarize yourself with [the protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). What are the `TE` and `Transfer-Encoding` headers of the response?

Comment: `PuTTyPuTTy...` is your client reacting to receiving what it perceived to be bad terminal control sequences. It's not safe to output arbitrary bytes to a terminal (as you are doing) since formatting codes are passed in bounds.

Comment: It may be gzipped, try to remove the accept-encoding header

Comment: and i have an encoding problem so? and one more question, do i have to re-arrange the sockets? They may be delays in sending.

Comment: i read here `TE` -> ` the client is willing to accept trailer fields in a chunked transfer-coding` witch basically say that my HTTP Request-Response is sended in chunked packets and my script does not know this, or how to deal with it, am i right?

Comment: @Miguel Prz `try to remove the accept-encoding header –` how do i do this? and it is safe? It might be bad to disable it ... `gzip` is good for increase the speed of the transfer ... I see here `Transfer-Encoding chunked` in ar requests (in Mozilla) witch means stat transfer is beeing chunked and my script is not capable to rearrange them yet ... right?

Comment: still no one have the answer?